# Hudson 3.3.3 compatibility with maven 3.2.5 issue

Tags: maven, hudson, osb

recently we have upgraded our Oracle Server Bus to 12.2.1 with Maven 3.2.5 and also upgraded Hudson from 3.2.2 to 3.3.3.
When executing mvn clean install build of type Build a Maven 2/3 project (Legacy) 
we are seeing errors.The same job runs with no errors in hudson 3.2.2 with maven 3.0.5. 
Also tried with Build a free-style software job and that picking default maven home and running osb plug in issues.

**Error:-**

```
[CommonResources] $ /oraapp/java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -cp /oraapp/hudson122_1/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-3.0.2.jar:/oraapp/1221/product/fmw/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /oraapp/1221/product/fmw/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.2.5 /oraapp/config/domains/soadevt/servers/soa_server1/tmp/_WL_user/hudson1221/vwczzi/war/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-3.0.3.jar /oraapp/hudson122_1/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-3.0.2.jar 41686
<===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /oraapp/hudson122_1/jobs/CommonResources_S-TFSIHUB_1221/workspace/CommonResources/pom.xml clean install -Dgroupid=CSSIntegrationhub_CUSTSVC -Dversion=RL1.0_110717 -DoracleServerUrl=http://hostname:7001 -DoracleUsername=x2krkanu -DoraclePassword=******** -Dcustomization=CommonResources_DEV_CF.xml -DoracleHome=/oraapp/product/fmw
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:146)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:124)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:107)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:41)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:276)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 18 more
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:189)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:107)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:41)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:276)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:150)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:124)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:146)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenLoggerManager
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:73)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.cli.MavenLoggerManager
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 18 more
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: CommonResources_S-TFSIHUB_1221 #19 due to result: FAILURE
Notifying upstream projects of job completion`enter code here`
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I assume you are running Hudson with Java 7 ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454408/legacy-maven-2-job-type-plugin-with-maven-3-2-1-not-working

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes i am using Jdk 8 which required for my OSB applications.Anything lower than 8 will not work.

Comment: @PierreB.The provided link is not working to me. Instead of picking configure maven home Freestyle job pick Maven home from hudson directory ##Maven home: /oraapp/hudson122_1/maven/slavebundle/bundled-maven.

Comment: Based on the logoutput is looks like your installation in Hudson is not correct...furthermore why are you giving such options like groupId, version etc. on a Maven command line...